# Getting FlashVars From Class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a class set up and it looks like this:

```
package scripts
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public dynamic class Upload
    {
        public function Upload()
        {

        }

        public function getPostURL():String
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

And I am instantiating the class by doing:

```
var upload = new Upload();
var url:String = upload.getPostURL();
```

This works fine and I am able to get the string, but how would I modify the class to be able to return FlashVars? I have been searching for hours and haven't been able to find an answer.

I am setting the FlashVars using this:

```
<param name=FlashVars value="var=test" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any instance added to the stage you can use this code:
`root.loaderInfo.parameters.var`

**UPDATE**

```
package scripts
{
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;

    // If you want to use an Uplaod class like a container, 
    // then you should extend it from Sprite.
    public dynamic class Upload extends Shape
    {
        protected var _url:String = "";

        public function Upload()
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            _url = root.loaderInfo.parameters.var;
        }

        public function getPostURL():String
        {
            return _url;
        }
    }
}
```

In `Main.as`:

```
var upload = new Upload();
addChild(upload);
var url:String = upload.getPostURL();
```

Or another variant without an `Upload` class. In `Main.as`:

```
var url:String = loaderInfo.parameters.var;
```

Comment: I made the class extend Stage and am returning "root.loaderInfo.parameters.var" in the getPostURL function, but nothing is returned. The only error I get is that there is an error here: `var upload = new Upload();
var url:String = upload.getPostURL();`

Comment: Extending Stage does not mean it has been added to stage.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include your FlashVars in the `src` parameter for `<embed>` as well as the `<param>` tag you've used, eg:

```
<embed src="file.swf?var=test" />
```

These variables are accessible via `root.loaderInfo.parameters`.

You're able to read more about the [`LoadInfo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html) object [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html).